# Android 1 column and 2 column rows Grid or ListView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, multiple-columns

the past few days I've been searching to find the right solution to what i want to achieve in the following photo.

[image: Desired result]

I read all about Gridview that its not suitable for diffent columns in rows.
There are many posts in here that suggest ways to achieve this , but none provides a certain solution.
Some say to use Listview.

I use a web service to fetch images from a data base, and want there images to be clickable(setOnItemClickListener). The first row has one image , the 2nd  2 images , the 3rd one image and so..

I would appreciate if anyone can provide a good solution to this.

Comment: this looks like a listview to me. with an adapter that has a `getViewTypeCount()` of 2, with 2 different layouts.

Comment: I can imagine the layout with one imageview but im not sure how the 2 image layout will be. Will it be 2 imageviews with 2 different ids and how the adapter will handle these imageviews?

Comment: you'd definitely need 2 imageviews with different ids, yes. as for the adapter, you'd need a mechanism. either your data contains the 2 images for the odd items, or the adapter is able to give you 2 images for one item directly. I assume you have something like a list of images?

Comment: Im my fragment i use: adapter = new MainPageAdapter(getActivity(), categoriesList);
list.setAdapter(adapter); and then in adapter i have 2 types and goes like  :            if (type == 0 || type == 3 || type == 6 || type == 7 || type == 8 || type == 9) {vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_1column, null);
            } else {vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_2column, null);
            }ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.bannerimage);imageLoader.DisplayImage(categorytitles.get(MainPageFragment.TAG_URL), loader, thumb_image);(...) can you suggest?